# Get api token before each $http in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Using AngularJS for my application and for http post the server needs a token that we can get by http get. But I want to run the `token_generate()` function before each http call, because sometimes the token expires

```
token = function() {
    var api = AuthService.getToken();
    api.success(function (response) {
        var token = response.token;
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
    });
};
token();
```

Comment: create a ajaxService and send all your ajax calls using this service, and now you can send get token call before sending any ajax call

Comment: You may consider using interceptor and hook it with $httpProvider.interceptors, and get new token before each http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register an $http interceptor:

```js
(function(window, angular) {

function tokenizerConfig($httpProvider) {
  function registerInterceptors($q, $http, AuthenticationService) {
    var interceptors = {};
    
    interceptors.request = function(configs) {
      if(AuthenticationService.isTokenValid) {
        return $q.when(configs);
      }
      
      var qs = {};
      
      return $http
        .get(TOKEN_API, { cache: false, params: qs})
        .then(function(result) {
          AuthenticationService.setToken(result.data.token);
        
          return configs;
        })
      ;
    };
    
    return interceptors;
  }
  
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$http', 'AuthenticationService', registerInterceptors]);
}

angular
  .module('tokenizer', [])
  .config(['$httpProvider', tokenizerConfig])

})(window, window.angular);
```